# Monthly "box" with products idea

Tags: orders, customer, ce-1.9.1.0, recurring, product-type

I am building a webshop with cosmetics and hair-face care products. But I want to help my (mostly men) customers to create a "box" where they can put in some products. After they purchased it, I want to mail the customer (after a month) that his products from the box are ready for him.

#### Example:

Customer1 places 2 shampoos and 3 day-creams in his box. And he fills in that he uses this order for a month. Then after 3 weeks my shop has to mail the customer:

> Hi! Are you running out of products yet? Your box is ready! (LINK)

What's the most easy way to to this? Or is there a extension I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend this module for sending the email
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/follow-up-email.html
Im not sure what your link would be though, could you use something like this extension?
http://www.mageworx.com/shopping-list-magento-extension.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the follow-up. email. The shopping list extension is nearly what I need.. This one has no pre-installed shopping list. And that is what I want. You have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Any "follow up email" extension will do the trick and "your box is ready" can link to "reorder" (will require customer to log in):

```
/sales/order/reorder/id/$ORDERID
```